# Empty space on PrototypeCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I've a `UITableView` with 2 sections, the first is to show a `SegmentControl` and the second is to show my data. The section 2 is Ok, but on the secion of SegControl the component not fit on the right height.

StoryBoard

[image]

Result: The empty space appears below `UISegmentedControl` of cell.

[image]

I tried many ways to solve this:

```
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath.section == 1 {
        return 100
    }
    return 44.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0.0
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return UIView()
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    if section == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    .
    .
    }
```

**EDIT**

I discovered that this blank space is the Footer, but I don't know How hide this.

[image]

```
        func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForFooterInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let view = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 0, height: 0))
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        return view
   }
```

Comment: Do you use AutoLayout?

Comment: Yes, I seted constraints 0-0-0-0.

Comment: Change 0 to 1 pt for bottom constraint.

Comment: Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE:
It is section footer view that is adding extra space, not the cell itself.

Use `heightForFooterInSection`. Following code should be able to solve your issue.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
      return 0
    }
    return UITableView.automaticDimension
}
```

Comment: This might violate if the cell has to expand dynamically.

Comment: Not works, this only change size of my `UISegmentedControl`. The blank space keeping. https://imgur.com/KlYhkpM

Comment: @Augusto `heightForFooterInSection` delegate too, see update answer

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that problem was the Footer of the Section, so I do this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if section == 0 {
        return 0
    }
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

and solves my problem.